# Selecting NULL or date values by Expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, date, null, qgsexpression, select-by-expression

How can I select by expression from a date field in a shapefile, dates that are NULL or >= 2020-01-01?

This doesn't work, it only selects those with `dates >= 2020-01-01`, not the `NULL`s

```
"field" is NULL OR "field" > '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know why, but this worked:

```
to_date(field) IS NULL or field > '2020-01-01'
```

Type of `"field"` is date.